# R: XML file to data frame

Tags: r, xml, dataframe

I'm fairly new to working with XML files within the R environment, but I have at least come further in making it work normally than I have with the specific file.

*Quick background:* I receive data in the attached format, but I cannot convert the data into a data frame (which I have succeeded in with other files.) Somehow my normal procedure doesn't work with this. My goal is to make the data into a data frame. Normally I would just use `xmlToDataFrame()`, but that provides me with the following error:

> unable to find an inherited method for function ‘xmlToDataFrame’ for
> signature ‘"xml_document", "missing", "missing", "missing", "missing"’

Then I tried the below sequence

```
data = read_xml("file.xml")
xmlimport = xmlTreeParse("file.xml")
topxml = xmlRoot(xmlimport)
topxml = xmlSApply(topxml,function(x) xmlSApply(x,xmlValue))
```

That provided me with the attached picture as output. All the data is contained within the cells, and I cannot seem to access the data. I feel like there is a really simple solution, but after working with the file for longer than I like to admit, I hope you can point something (hopefully) obvious out to me.

If you have the time to assist me in it, I've uploaded the file [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/a6f8b63597eee19c197dc9155e5d629620220530135545/6e8363)

Hope that will do.

Thanks for taking the time to assist me.

Note: The data is a bank fee statement, and the data is completely fictional

[Output result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Vyxl.png)

Comment: Hi Chris - your link is broken I'm afraid, so it's impossible to help you here unless you can post a more stable link or a reproducible snippet. Thanks

Comment: Hi Allan. Thanks for the heads-up - I've updated the link to a more stable one.

Comment: Please post a *minimal* sample of XML in body of question (not as an image) for future readers since links can break in the future.